# How HashSet create hashkey for the object or value

Tags: java, hashset

I am little bit confused about HashSet internal working, as i know HashSet uses key(K) to find the right bucket and equals used to compare values but how HashSet works means how it generate hash Key ?

Comment: It calls the object's `hashCode` method. Is that all you need?

Comment: see the source code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashSet.java.html

Comment: @user2357112 in fact `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap` and in there, there is a supplementary `hash` function (`hash(hascode)` is used).

Comment: How about taking a peek into atcual implementation's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here it is

```
final int hash(Object k) {
    int h = hashSeed;
    if (0 != h && k instanceof String) {
        return sun.misc.Hashing.stringHash32((String) k);
    }

    h ^= k.hashCode();

    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

it's actually in HashMap which HashSet uses internally

Answer (score 1):

Internally HashSet use HashMap,the hash key of the value is generated and used to save the element in HashTable.

To generate HashCode of the element the method `HashCode()` is called

Below method of HashMap to put element which is internally used by HashSet to add element :

```
 public V put(K paramK, V paramV)
      {
        if (paramK == null)
          return putForNullKey(paramV);
        int i = hash(paramK.hashCode());
-----------------------------^
        // More code
      }
```